# Как добавить .dll файл в Xamarin.Forms проект?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

В обычном C# проекте я просто скопировал этот .dll в папку проекта и использовал

```
[DllImport("***.dll")]
```

В случае с Xamarin при компиляции получаю .dll Not Found Exeption. Добавить ссылку на файл не получается из-за его формата. Возможно ли как-то добавить этот .dll в Xamarin.Forms проект?

Comment: `Возможно ли как-то добавить этот .dll` а этот dll вообще поддерживается Xamarin?

Comment: @tym32167 А как это проверить?

Comment: без понятия, вы узнайте там, откуда вы её взяли.

Comment: @tym32167 Там где я его взял,я уже не узнаю. Думаю, если он работал с обычным C# проектом,то и с Xamarin должен как-то работать

Comment: А зависимости настроены?